# Why do not use universal reference to implement std::forward?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17

I knew there were probably already some similar questions on StackOverflow, but I didn't actually find anything that fully answered my doubts, so I asked my own question.

There are two different overloads of `std::forward`:

```cpp
template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type& t );

template< class T >
T&& forward( typename std::remove_reference<T>::type&& t );
```

What is the difference with one universal reference template function using `static_cast`? Like:

```
template<class T>
T&& myForward(T &&t) {
    return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

When I pass a rvalue of type `A`, `T` with be deduced to `A` and `myForward` will return `A &&`; When a lvalue is passed, `T` with be deduced to `A &`, and it will return `A &`. So what is the difference?

I understand the notion that the second overload can prohibit forwarding a rvalue to a lvalue, but why `myForward` cannot?

Comment: The second overload prevents/prohibits passing rvalues as lvalues. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward)

Comment: It's strange that I could google the dupe for a second, but you could not, and spent a minute at least for writing the question.

Comment: Adrian could you give me a more concrete example of this kind of behavior?

Comment: `myForward` will deduce `T` from the arg, like `myForward(int())`, that is not desired, because all params of a caller are lvalues.

Comment: You mean because we also want to pass lvalue as rvalue, so `myForward` is not enough?

Comment: Sorry I did not get you, I thought `static_cast` will convert lvalue arguments to rvalues.

Comment: I mean `myForward` leads to hard to debug bugs. On of possible bugs is described in the dupe.

Comment: Thinking about lack of competence of C++ Committee and C++ standard library authors is not productive. The dupe has a reference to the proposal, it very clearly explains the reason for such implementation with a visual table.